# JFrame launches different size every launch

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My Java JFrame launches a different size almost every time I launch it. It is either the size I want it to be (800x600) or too small to do anything with it.

```
public static void initFrame() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}
```

I'm launching from another class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Frame.initFrame();
        }
});
```

Comment: I tried the code and the size is fixed ... so what is the real problem ?

Comment: The main culprit is the call to `setVisible ( true )`, much before, the components are actually added to the `JFrame` ( as `JFrame`'s size is not yet realized ). First add components to the `JFrame` and then call `setVisible ( true )` afterwards

Comment: And don't forget to `pack()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end so that the compiler will read the size of the `JFrame` before making it visible.